# How to return a String from a Future<String> in Dart for a chat app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, asynchronous

In a chat app I'm trying to query Firestore and return the other user's name as a String from a 'Contacts' collection. I'm still trying to wrap my head around async and Futures in dart, so when I return this, it prints 'Instance of Future' instead of the string that findName should query for.

```
return ListView(
                    children: List.generate(_conversations.length, (i) {
                      

                      DocumentReference? _conversationRef =
                          _conversations[i].reference;
                      Map _conversation = _conversations[i].data() ?? {};



                      String otherUser = _conversation["members"][0] != uid
                          ? _conversation["members"][0]
                          : _conversation["members"][1];



                      Future<String> findName(otherUser) async {
                        var recipName = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection("contacts")
                            .where("phone_number", isEqualTo: otherUser)
                            .get().then(

                              (querySnapshot) {
                                 for (var docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {

                                   return docSnapshot.data()['full_name'].toString();
                                 }
                              });


                            if (recipName != null) {
                              return recipName;
                            } else {
                              return otherUser;
                            }
                      }

                      
                      contactName() async {
                        var name = await findName(otherUser);
                        return name.toString();
                      }


                      return ConversationTile(
                          conversationReference: _conversationRef,
                          otherUserId: contactName() ?? "user number");
                    }),
```

Comment: 1. You obtain a `T` from a `Future<T>` by using `await`.  2. Use `await` instead of `Futuer.then`. Read https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Answer (score 0):

If you are building UI off of a future, you want to use FutureBuilder, it makes controlling the state of the result of the future and rendering the ui once the future is complete. Below is a  simple example of FutureBuilder, i can provide more details if needed.

```
FutureBuilder(
 future: getMessages(),
 builder:(context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) { // Future Complete 
   return ListView.builder(itemBuilder:(context, index) {
    //build listview 
   },);
  }
 },
 return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()); // Future Not Complete / No Data
),
```

Answer (score 0):

In Dart you can return a String from a Future by using the async and await keywords. Follow this link https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

In your case updated code will be-

```
return ListView(
  children: List.generate(_conversations.length, (i) {
    DocumentReference? _conversationRef = _conversations[i].reference;
    Map _conversation = _conversations[i].data() ?? {};

    String otherUser = _conversation["members"][0] != uid
        ? _conversation["members"][0]
        : _conversation["members"][1];

    Future<String> findName(String otherUser) async {
      var querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("contacts")
          .where("phone_number", isEqualTo: otherUser)
          .get();

      for (var docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
        return docSnapshot.data()['full_name'].toString();
      }

      return otherUser;
    }

    return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: findName(otherUser),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ConversationTile(
            conversationReference: _conversationRef,
            otherUserId: snapshot.data!,
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}");
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }),
);
```

Comment: You shouldn’t run the async function in the future in future builder because then this function will run every time you build the widget. you should call it in initState or somewhere else (Without using await) and use the variable in the future in future builder. 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html (Managing the future)